# Не получается работать с библиотекой cv2 в pycharm

Tags: python, cv2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Хочу работать с компьютерным зрением, но не могу настроить работу с библиотекой cv2. Сначала после загрузки у меня подсвечивались методы, при наведении курсора высвечивается надпись Cannot find reference 'imread' in '**init**.py'. Прочитал о этой проблеме в интернете, узнал, что можно изменить интерпретатор. Получилось следующее: методы так же подсвечиваются, но код запускается. Проблема теперь в том, что у меня вместо изображения выводится чёрный экран. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я могу сделать и как это решить?

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
cv2.imshow('result', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Будьте любезны, покажите ваш скрипт.

Comment: `import cv2
    
                                                                      img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
                                                                      cv2.imshow('result', img)
    
                                                                      cv2.waitKey(0)`

Comment: Добавьте скрипт в вопрос, нажмите править, и соблюдайте форматирование.

Comment: Ещё вам нужно добавить ваше изображение как есть. Может ваше изображение состоит целиком из чёрных пикселей, откуда нам знать.

Comment: Все, у меня заработало! Спасибо большое Вам! Правда, я не совсем понял, что была за ошибка( я поменял изображение(на то,которое указал). Так же я заметил,что библиотеки подгружались в другую папку, откуда я их переместил в папку проекта(честно, я так и раньше делал, но у меня ничего не работало и никаких функций не видело). Возможно, дело было еще в том, что я использловал opencv_contrib_python-4.6.0.66.dist-info, а потом поменял эту версию на opencv_python-4.5.5.62.dist-info. В любом случае, менялось несколько факторов, и я не совсем понял, который из них мешал мне работать.

Comment: По идее библиотеки ставятся в специальную директорию, отведённую для этих целей. С этим вам нужно разобраться.